# Differential Equation (Advertising Model)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In the sales response to advertising model given by $S'=-(a+ rA(t)/M)S+ rA(t)$, where a,M and r are constants. Assume that $S(0) = S_0$ and that advertising is constant A over a fixed time period T , and is then removed. That is,
$A(t) =  A$ when $0 ≤ t ≤ T$  and $A(t)= 0, t > T $
Find a formula for the sales $S(t)$ for every time t.

I'm a little bit lost since A is defined in two intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $A$ is discontinuous, you need to solve separately in both regions.  So when $t \in [0,T]$, you have

$$S_-' + \left ( a +\frac{r A_0}{M} \right ) S_- = r A_0$$

(I am calling the constant $A_0$ to avoid confusion with the function $A$.)

In general, the solution to the equation

$$S_-'+k S_-=C \quad S_-(0)=S_0$$

where $k=a+\frac{r A_0}{M}$ and $C=r A_0$ is

$$S_-(t) = S_0 e^{-k t} + \frac{C}{k} \left ( 1-e^{-k t}\right )$$

I'll let you derive the result and finish the algebra.  Now, when $t\gt T$, the equation is

$$S_+'+a S_+=0 \implies S_+(t)=B e^{-a t}$$

To find $B$, assume continuity of $S$ at $t=T$.  This means that $S_+(T) = S_-(T)$.  Why assume this?  It is assumed that the sales behavior, as a response to the advertising behavior, is smooth despite the discontinuity in the advertising.  (This is common in physics as well.)

Thus,

$$S_0 e^{-k T} + \frac{C}{k} \left ( 1-e^{-k T}\right ) = B e^{-a T}$$

and you would solve for $B$.